# Postgres String to Array conversion with backslash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql

I have a string in postgres table: `["abc", "123", "zzz"]`

Postgres table column data type is citext.

When I display the above string in Rails view: `["[\"abc\", \"123\", \"zzz\"]"]`

How do I convert the string in postgres table into an array to get `["abc, "123", "zzz"]` in Rails view?

Comment: May `JSON.parse()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `JSON.parse()`. For example:

```
> array = JSON.parse('["abc", "123", "zzz"]')
 => ["abc", "123", "zzz"] 
> array.first
 => "abc"
```

Btw postgres support array column.